# Verifier /standard /all can we use it regularly?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I didn't know about this marvelous command until recently encountered driver conflicts which were only resolved by windows reinstall. (wrethed "IRQL less than or equal")

Now I am using fresh install and after I installed rapport(identity protection software) this command immediately flagged BSOD with the name of the app.

Since it is so good at checking system stability and conflicts I wondered whether I need to turn it off at all?

After all after every few installs I can restart the machine and see if all is compatible.

Or the feature gives negative impact on performance or can't be used under heavy loads such as video decoding or gaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activating Drive Verifier indeed does hit the Performance. You should only activate it if you get bugchecks (BSOD) and the dumps don't show you the causing drivers.

If it helped you to find the app, disable it and only activate it again if you get new issues.